# How and by which frequency capture screenshot of unity game for short in-gave video?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I learned to capture screenshot from unity game and I'm having my HD ones happily. By my still poor knowledge of animation I can't understand how many screenshots and with what delay to get from unity to render a reasonable quality mpeg video later in blender, say, for a 3 minute clip?

Any link to a tutorial is very welcomed. I sure found ready exntensions for in-game video from unity, but I want to DIY to learn something!

Comment: Look no further than this. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-captureFramerate.html . The variable frame rate will allow you to set frame rate capture. Default is set at 25 but I have tested it with 60 also. For three minutes it should be around 4500 screenshots taken at 25 FPS 25*60*3 = 4500. Video Playbacks are kept at 24fps but ofcourse you can make them at 60. Try with this and lets us know what else you need.

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused (I know to many this is little school algebra), the default variable is "public int frameRate = 25;" does that mean that based on written there "If this property has a non-zero value then frame update will occur at an interval of (1.0 / captureFramerate)" I just setup a counter to stop after capturing 4500 screenshots? I think I'm confused by the first 60 being what you said you tried, and the next 60 in the formula you provided as seconds of a minute. Overall, for a normal video default "frameRate = 25;" and a counter for 4500 is enough?

Comment: Yes. FPS means frames drawn on screen per second. A movie is by default renders at 24 FPS means 24 frames will drawn in one second of movie. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_rate. So for 3 minutes clip you have 180 sec. If you want to create clip at 24 FPS you multiply it by 180 24*180 = 4320(stop after this count and you have your rendered images ready to import in blender). What I mentioned above is default framerate in unity source code which they have kept it.

Comment: If you decide to make it 30 you will need more screenshots a total of 5400. Also here is article which you can read about frame rates https://gizmodo.com/why-frame-rate-matters-1675153198.

Comment: Thank you now it's clear, I will do the rendering and report back here.